# Ruby expression evaluation: whitespace matters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Imagine it's Jan 19. This will not be hard if you look at this question today.

```
Date.today
 => Thu, 19 Jan 2012    # as expected

Date.today + 1
 => Fri, 20 Jan 2012    # as expected

Date.today+1
 => Fri, 20 Jan 2012    # as expected

Date.today +1
 => Thu, 19 Jan 2012    # ?!
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference is that:

```
Date.today + 1
```

is an addition of two numerical values and

```
Date.today +1
```

is a call to the method `today` with the parameter `sg`(day of calendar reform) with value `+1`

The best way to examine this is to monkey patch the original method with debug output included. See this script as example:

```
require 'date'

class Date

  def self.today(sg=ITALY)
     puts "ITALY default("+sg.to_s+")" if sg==ITALY
     puts sg unless sg==ITALY
     jd = civil_to_jd(*(Time.now.to_a[3..5].reverse << sg))
     new0(jd_to_ajd(jd, 0, 0), 0, sg)
  end

end

puts "- Addition:"
Date.today + 1
puts "- Parameter:"
Date.today +1
```

This will print the following console output:

```
- Addition:
ITALY default(2299161)
- Parameter:
1
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, whitespace *does* matter in Ruby, contrary to popular belief. For example, `foo bar` is not the same as `foobar`.

In this particular case,

```
Date.today + 1
```

is the same as

```
Date.today().+(1)
```

Whereas

```
Date.today +1
```

is the same as

```
Date.today(+1)
```

which is the same as

```
Date.today(1.+@())
```